# Swift: Better way to search for the index of an array containing a number inside an array?

Tags: arrays, swift

Curious to know if there is a better way to do this. I have an array of arrays that contain integers. All the integers are unique. I want to search for a given number and return the index of the first array. I don't care what the index is of the array containing the numbers.

This does what I want but I'm new to swift and figured there is a better way.

```
let arr:[[Int]] = [[0], [1], [2, 3], [4], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10]]

var t = -1
for q in arr {
    t += 1
    if let x = q.index(of: 13) { // <-- looking for the index that contains 13
        print ("t: \(t)") // <-- this is what I want. Returns '4'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
let arr: [[Int]] = [[0], [1], [2, 3], [4], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10]]

for (i, a) in arr.enumerated() {
    if let _ = a.index(of: 13) {
        print(i)
    }
}
```

It makes use of the `enumerated()` method of collections. It returns a tuple containing the index of the array `i` and the actual element of the array `a`.

#### Using functional programming

Here's the functional programming version if that's more your style:

```
arr.enumerated().map { $0 }.map { i, a in
    if let _ = a.index(of: 13) { 
        print(i) 
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great. Thanks! I ran across this in the documentation but couldn't get it to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

A solution without loop using `index(where:`

```
let arr: [[Int]] = [[0], [1], [2, 3], [4], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10]]

if let index = arr.index(where: { $0.contains(13) }) {
    print(index)
} else {
    print("not found")
}
```